# customize the display format of tsibble yearmonth column?

Tags: r, time, series, tsibble, yearmonth

Can I customize the display format of the time series column in tsibble ?

yearmonth allways like %Y %m，but i would like change the default format to %m-%y all over one chunk

## tsibble::format not working

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for `format('%b-%Y')`?

```r
df <- data.frame(
  date = c("2022-01-01","2022-02-01","2022-03-01",
           "2022-04-01","2022-05-01","2022-06-01","2022-07-01",
           "2022-08-01","2022-09-01","2022-10-01","2022-11-01","2022-12-01")
)

df |>
  dplyr::mutate(
    date = tsibble::yearmonth(date) |>
      format('%b-%Y')
  )
#>        date
#> 1  Jan-2022
#> 2  Feb-2022
#> 3  Mar-2022
#> 4  Apr-2022
#> 5  May-2022
#> 6  Jun-2022
#> 7  Jul-2022
#> 8  Aug-2022
#> 9  Sep-2022
#> 10 Oct-2022
#> 11 Nov-2022
#> 12 Dec-2022
```

Another option is to use `zoo::yearmon()`.

```r
df |>
  dplyr::mutate(
    date = zoo::as.yearmon(date)
  )
#>        date
#> 1  Jan 2022
#> 2  Feb 2022
#> 3  Mar 2022
#> 4  Apr 2022
#> 5  May 2022
#> 6  Jun 2022
#> 7  Jul 2022
#> 8  Aug 2022
#> 9  Sep 2022
#> 10 Oct 2022
#> 11 Nov 2022
#> 12 Dec 2022
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I give a option(...) at the beginning or other ways,  then  use " ts <- dplyr::mutate(df,date =tsibble::yearmonth(date)); print(ts)" all over the code?

Comment: @ZenoShuai Another option is to use `zoo::yearmon()`.  That automatically prints the way you want it (assuming the hyphen isn't needed). I updated my answer to show that option.